trigger submit on several forms at once in javascript
We have hera at school an older learning platform with low usability. I try to improve it by writing an add-on for me and my collegues. I got som stuff working but i am stuck trying to submit several forms att once. The task is the following: On the webpage is a list of all my students. There is one textarea for each one for assesment and a link "Save" to update and set the current date and time as timestamp for the text.
The link triggers a method which copies some parameters to a form and submits it. it is know a Asp.net Postback Mechanism(doPostBack function).
I would like to trigger that in a loop for all student so every assesment, even empty once, gets a new timestamp just to confirm and older assesment as still valid.
I got a functioning loop but only the first submit works. Thats dues to the fact that a subimt triggers a full request and it reload the page --> The loop stops.
Workaround: the script copies the form to an iframe the prevent reoload. Works, but the problem is now that only the last student in the loop is uppdated.
I guessed it was about timing, the requests are coming to fast for the server. So i slowed it down to 5sec wait between request but only the last student shows an updated timestamp.
I need another idea to fix this. Here is my code so far. count and if(count<3) i only for debugging purposes:
document.getElementById('saveAll').addEventListener('click', () => {
    addText = document.getElementById('add2BoxText').value;

    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {
                tabId: tabs[0].id
            },
            function: saveAllBoxes

        });
    });
});







function saveAllBoxes() {

    var c = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];

    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    const formClone = theForm.cloneNode(true);
    iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(formClone);
    //document.body.removeChild(theForm); 


    if (!formClone) {
        formClone = document.aspnetForm;
    }

    async function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!formClone.onsubmit || (formClone.onsubmit() != false)) {
            formClone.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            formClone.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

            formClone.submit();
            console.log(formClone.__EVENTTARGET.value);
            c++;
        }
    }

    count = 0;
    var all_td_a = document.querySelectorAll('td a');
    
    all_td_a.forEach((element) => {

        if (element.text == 'Spara') {
            element.text = "Saved";
            fullLink = element.href;
            var fullLink = fullLink.substring(fullLink.indexOf("'") + 1, fullLink.lastIndexOf("'") - 3);
            //console.log(fullLink);
            nu = new Date().valueOf() + 2500;
            console.log('---',nu);
            while (nu > new Date().valueOf()) {
                // my kind of loop. bad! but i did not get SetTimeout to work.
            }
            console.log(new Date().valueOf());
           if(count < 3) __doPostBack(fullLink, '');
            count++;
           
        }


    });
   
}

